# Retrieve all records attached to multiple users in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

How to retrieve all records which had been attached to multiple users, please? For example I need each and every post attached to either user A, B or C. I've `belongsToMany` relationship set correctly, but don't know how to merge them all together. Thank you!

Posts below are attached to each user by `belongsToMany` relationship.
User A - Post 1 / Post 2
User B - Post 3 / Post 4 / Post 5
User C - Post 3 / Post 5 / Post 6
Now, for User D I need an eloquent of all these Posts (Post 1,2,3,4,5,6).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you just query through users ID's? Like so:

```
$posts = Post::whereHas('users', function($q) use($usersIds) {
    $q->whereIn('id', $usersIds);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

Since posts are attached to user by belongsToMany relationship, you can simply use the relationship from Post model to fetch the data. Suppose  users is the name of relationship in Post model.

```
$result = Post::with('users')->whereIn('id',$userIds)->get();
```

Comment: No, this doesn't work for some reason.. but looks better. Thanks anyway...